# Create a column in a dataframe based on probabilities stored in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, probability, data-wrangling

I have a python dataframe, pop, which has a few hundred thousand rows, the first of which are presented here:

**pop:**

| Index | Unique_ID | Code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5426845315 | 1 |
| 1 | 5426848464 | 6 |
| 2 | 5484651315 | 1 |
| 3 | 5426808654 | 39 |

...

I want to create another column in this dataframe based on the value in the "code" and another dataframe, prob, which contains the probability of a value of 1, 2, or 3 appearing for each code.

**prob:**

| Index | Code | Prob_1 | Prob_2 | Prob_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0.50 | 0.25 | 0.25 |
| 1 | 2 | 0.80 | 0.10 | 0.10 |

...

I'm trying to apply the values "1", "2", or "3" to each row in the pop dataframe depending on the probabilities associated with the value in the "Code" row in the prob dataframe.

So far, I've tried this, but it didn't work, seems as though I can't use iloc when listing probabilities.

```
response = [1,2,3]   
def categorise_response(row):
        if row['Code'] == 1:
              return random.choice(response, 1, p=[prob.iloc[0][Prob_1], prob.iloc[0][Prob_2], prob.iloc[0][Prob_3]])
```

I get the error:

> TypeError: choice() got an unexpected keyword argument 'p'

There's probably a much better way to do this, I'm a bit of a python novice, so any help is appreciated.

Edited to add:

I'm hoping to get an output like this, where a column "response" is added to the pop dataframe that includes a value based on the probabilities in the table prob:

**New pop:**

| Index | Unique_ID | Code | Response |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 5426845315 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 5426848464 | 6 | 3 |
| 2 | 5484651315 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 5426808654 | 39 | 1 |

...

Comment: Add your expected output here to understand better

Comment: Thanks, I've added a table to make it a bit clearer, does that help?

Comment: Where are you importing `random` from? The `choice` function from the built-in [random module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) doesn't take a `p` parameter, you would need to use the `weights` parameter in `random.choices()` for that. If you want to use `p` for probabilities, you would need to use the [numpy.random.choice](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) function

Answer (score 0):

[`random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) allows you to use a `weights` sequence. So, if you want for each row of `pop` a `response` based on the distributions in `prob`, then you could try:

```
from random import choices

response = [1,2,3]
def categorise_response(row):
    return choices(response, weights=row[["Prob_1", "Prob_2", "Prob_3"]], k=1)[0]

pop["Response"] = (
    pop.merge(prob, on="Code", how="left").apply(categorise_response, axis=1)
)
```

To build the new `Response` column:

- [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) `prob` on `pop` along the `Code` column.
- Then [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) the `categorise_response` function on each row: The function uses `choices` on `response` with the `weights` from the `Prob_...` columns.

If you don't want individual draws for each row of `pop`, then you could try:

```
pop["Response"] = pop[["Code"]].merge(
    prob.assign(Response=prob.apply(categorise_response, axis=1)),
    on="Code", how="left"
)["Response"]
```

(But your example indicates that this is not the case.)